# The MFC ComboBox dropdown button is missing after using SetDroppedWidth

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, gdi

This is an Windows MFC programming issue.
I have a derived CComboBox which implement its own item draw and measurement. I did a little enhancement that the drop down list width is adjustable based on the list content.
I use SetDroppedWidth in OnDropDown message handler to do it.
After I insert strings and click the combo box, the selected string content seized all static/edit area, and drop down button is missing.
I could see the width of the item, which has item ID -1, is changed/reset to the new dropped width in ItemDraw method. I don't think this is the right behavior. I want the new dropped width only take effect on list items, item ID of which is not less than 0.
Any idea?

Comment: try to call SetDroppedWidth after you initialise the combobox items. I think calling it inside the OnDropDown method is not a right place

Comment: But in this way, the combobox width could only be adjusted once, because the initialization is called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this.

In your OnDropDown handler Call [CComboBox::GetComboBoxInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z6k2dt8t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It will return you the pointer of `COMBOBOXINFO` structure. This structure among the others contains the HWND of the dropdown listbox `hwndList`. Use MoveWindow() API on this hwndList directly and see if it works

If that does not work, try posting the `CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH` message. As you know, `SetDroppedWidth` is just a wrapper for `CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH` message. It is implemented as a `SendMessage` call. Try this one:

```
::PostMessage(m_myComboBox.GetSafeHwnd(), CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH, nWidth, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Why you choose PostMessage but not SendMessage?

Comment: Usually when you send the message from within a message handler it leads to all sort of troubles. Posting the message just places it into the message queue.